# Check code as a string instead of parsing a file

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to use `checkcode` or `matlab.internal.codeanalyzer` to parse a string of code, for example:

```
for i=1:100 a*b(i); end
```

without first putting that in a file and then calling `checkcode` or the internal `parser.parse` on that file. I want to check thousands of strings of code but dynamically without putting them in a file before each check. Ideally, I would like to be able to parse a string with the code in and have that parsed.

To be more clear incase there are other functions that could be useful, I actually want to parse a string and count the number of syntax errors, and find their location etc.

Comment: After traversing the full source of checkcode and googling everywhere, the only answer I came up with is: no. The parsing of files is performed so deep internally that you already working at MEX level... the only solution is to use temporary files as you said.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo Oh OK, annoying. How about mimicking the write/read to/from the file without actually involving IO? Like using a file but that is actually in RAM.

Comment: This makes no sense. Either a file exists, or it doesn't. A file loaded into memory is not a file. And this function wants a file, and by file I mean a physical file written on the disk.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo OK never mind, I was thinking along the lines of whether it was possible to use Memory-Mapping

Comment: Memory-mapping was a dead end, but I found a `-text` option. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems `mlintmex` has a `-text` option which one can use to pass a string. It needs a string and a filename, however, it seems not to even use the filename, so not sure why. Furthermore, I can't figure out why, but when using `-text` there needs to be at least one parseable command. Therefore instead of calling

```
fid = fopen('tmp.m','wt');
fprintf(fid, '-mean[1:10)');
fclose(fid);
info = checkcode('tmp.m', '-fullpath');
```

one can use the following which has a great increase in performance:

```
% Get the errors with text mode
info = checkcode(['1;','-mean[1:10)'], 'tmp.m', '-fullpath', '-text');
% Reduce the columns to take in to account the '1;' in the checkcode call above.
for i=1:numel(info)
    info(i).column = info(i).column - 2;
end
```

Using `tic` and `toc` in a loop for 1000 times, I get ~9 seconds for the file version and ~3-4 seconds for the `-text` version.